# Switch dynamic database from other DB in Codeigniter

Tags: database, codeigniter, dynamic, switch-statement, multiple-databases

mi file config.php is:

```
$active_group = 'default';
$active_record = TRUE;
```

db master is unique DB

```
$db['master']['hostname'] = "localhost";
$db['master']['username'] = "root"; 
$db['master']['password'] = ""; 
$db['master']['database'] = "admin_nb";
$db['master']['dbdriver'] = "mysqli"; 
$db['master']['dbprefix'] = ''; 
$db['master']['pconnect'] = FALSE; 
$db['master']['db_debug'] = TRUE; 
$db['master']['cache_on'] = FALSE; 
$db['master']['cachedir'] = ""; 
$db['master']['char_set'] = "utf8"; 
$db['master']['dbcollat'] = "utf8_general_ci";
```

db app is DYNAMIC DB

```
$db['app']['hostname'] = 'localhost';
$db['app']['username'] = 'root';
$db['app']['password'] = '';
$db['app']['database'] = $my_bd_dynamic;
$db['app']['dbdriver'] = 'mysqli';
$db['app']['dbprefix'] = '';
$db['app']['pconnect'] = TRUE;
$db['app']['db_debug'] = TRUE;
$db['app']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
$db['app']['cachedir'] = '';
$db['app']['char_set'] = 'utf8';
$db['app']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';
$db['app']['swap_pre'] = '';
$db['app']['autoinit'] = TRUE;
$db['app']['stricton'] = FALSE;
```

According to a login in the master database, I get the name of the database and I have to assign the value to the variable
$ My_bd_dynamic

The "bd_dynamic's" can not write it manually because many databases

I was testing this in my controller:

```
class Trabajador extends CI_Controller {
public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();

    $this->load->driver('cache');
    $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url','otros_helper','fechas_helper','imagen_helper'));
    // Se le asigna a la informacion a la variable $user.
    $this->abbost_hotel = @$this->session->userdata('sess_abbost_hotel_'.substr(base_url(),-8,7));

        $my_bd_dynamic= $this->abbost_hotel->nombre_bd; /*var session*/
        $config_app['hostname'] = 'localhost';
        $config_app['username'] = 'root';
        $config_app['password'] = '';
        $config_app['database'] = $my_bd_dynamic;
        $config_app['dbdriver'] = 'mysqli';
        $config_app['dbprefix'] = '';
        $config_app['pconnect'] = FALSE;
        $config_app['db_debug'] = TRUE;
        $this->load->model('model_tareas','',$config_app);

}
public function index()
{
    //...
}
```

And, my Model_tarea is:
...

```
 public function m_cargar_tareas_activas()
    {
        $estado = 1;
        $this->db->select("colum1,colum2");
        $this->db->from('tarea');
        $query = $this->db->get();
        return $query->result_array();
    }
```

...
But, read database master and not read database $my_bd_dynamic.
Help Please,
There is no way to manipulate this way?

```
$this->set->database = $my_dinamic_bd;
```

What part of the core of codeigniter I have to change to fix the problem?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Thanks, thiagobraga.
But...

```
public function m_cargar_tareas_activas($group_name)
{
    ...
```

its parameter $group_name, would have to go for all my methods
My solution is:

**database.php**

```
$active_group = 'master';
$active_record = TRUE;
$db['master']['hostname'] = "localhost";
$db['master']['username'] = "root"; 
$db['master']['password'] = ""; 
$db['master']['database'] = "admin_nb";
$db['master']['dbdriver'] = "mysqli"; 
$db['master']['dbprefix'] = ''; 
$db['master']['pconnect'] = FALSE; 
$db['master']['db_debug'] = TRUE; 
$db['master']['cache_on'] = FALSE; 
$db['master']['cachedir'] = ""; 
$db['master']['char_set'] = "utf8"; 
$db['master']['dbcollat'] = "utf8_general_ci";
```

My new file helper:

**db_dinamic_helper**

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
function switch_db_dinamico($name_db)
{
    $config_app['hostname'] = 'localhost';
    $config_app['username'] = 'root';
    $config_app['password'] = '';
    $config_app['database'] = $name_db;
    $config_app['dbdriver'] = 'mysqli';
    $config_app['dbprefix'] = '';
    $config_app['pconnect'] = FALSE;
    $config_app['db_debug'] = TRUE;
    return $config_app;
}
```

**trabajador.php**

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
class Trabajador extends CI_Controller {
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->driver('cache');
        $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url','otros_helper','fechas_helper','imagen_helper','config_helper','permisos_helper'));
        $this->abbost_hotel = @$this->session->userdata('sess_abbost_hotel_'.substr(base_url(),-8,7));
        if(!@$this->abbost_hotel->usuario_id) redirect ('acceso');

            $nombre_bd = $this->abbost_hotel->nombre_bd;
            $config_app = switch_db_dinamico($nombre_bd);
            $this->load->model(array('model_producto','model_trabajadores','model_habitacion','model_tareas','model_notif'));
            $this->model_trabajadores->app_db = $this->load->database($config_app,TRUE);
            $this->model_habitacion->app_db = $this->load->database($config_app,TRUE);
            $this->model_producto->app_db = $this->load->database($config_app,TRUE);
            $this->model_tareas->app_db = $this->load->database($config_app,TRUE);
            $this->model_notif->app_db = $this->load->database($config_app,TRUE);
         date_default_timezone_set("America/Lima");
        //if(!@$this->user) redirect ('inicio/login');
        //$permisos = cargar_permisos_del_usuario($this->user->idusuario);
    }
    public function index()
    {
        //...
    }
```

...And my model:

**model_tareas.php**

```
<?php
class Model_tareas extends CI_Model {
    public $app_db;
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }
    public function m_cargar_tareas_activas()
    {
        $estado = 1;
        $this->app_db->select("tarea_id, prioridad");
        $this->app_db->from('tarea');
        $query = $this->app_db->get();
        return $query->result_array();
    }
```

IMPORTANT¡
The file db_dinamic_helper.php initialize in file autoload.php
Thanks..¡¡ :)

Answer (score 1):

### database.php

```php
$active_group  = 'master';
$active_record = TRUE;

// SQL Server
$db['master']['hostname'] = "localhost";
$db['master']['username'] = "root"; 
$db['master']['password'] = ""; 
$db['master']['database'] = "admin_nb";
$db['master']['dbdriver'] = "mysqli"; 
$db['master']['dbprefix'] = ''; 
$db['master']['pconnect'] = FALSE; 
$db['master']['db_debug'] = TRUE; 
$db['master']['cache_on'] = FALSE; 
$db['master']['cachedir'] = ""; 
$db['master']['char_set'] = "utf8"; 
$db['master']['dbcollat'] = "utf8_general_ci";
```

### trabajador.php

```php
class Trabajador extends CI_Controller
{

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();

        $this->load->driver('cache');
        $this->load->helper(array(
            'form',
            'url',
            'otros_helper',
            'fechas_helper',
            'imagen_helper'
        ));

        // Se le asigna a la informacion a la variable $user.
        $this->abbost_hotel = @$this->session->userdata(
            'sess_abbost_hotel_' . substr(base_url(), -8, 7)
        );

        $database_name = $this->abbost_hotel->nombre_bd; /*var session*/
        $config_app = array(
            'hostname' => 'localhost',
            'username' => 'root',
            'password' => '',
            'database' => $database_name,
            'dbdriver' => 'mysqli',
            'dbprefix' => '',
            'pconnect' => FALSE,
            'db_debug' => TRUE
        );

        $this->load->model('model_tareas');
        $result = Model_tareas::m_cargar_tareas_activas($config_app);
        var_dump($result);
    }

}
```

### model_tareas.php

```php
class Model_tareas extends CI_Model
{

    public function m_cargar_tareas_activas($group_name)
    {
        $server = $this->load->database($group_name);
        $estado = 1;
        $server->select("colum1,colum2");
        $server->from('tarea');
        $query = $server->get();
        return $query->result_array();
    }

}
```

Check the documentation of CodeIgniter in database section:
https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/connecting.html

> **Manually Connecting to a Database**
>
> The first parameter of this function can optionally be used to specify a particular database group from your config file, or you can even submit connection values for a database that is not specified in your config file. Examples:
>
> To choose a specific group from your config file you can do this:
>
> ```
>     $this->load->database('group_name');
> ```
>
> Where **group_name** is the name of the connection group from your config file.