# Dynamic Database in Codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I get the database information:

```
$data4shop['webshops'] = $this->Product_shop_model->getWebshop($businessId)->result();
```

I only need to insert it into the database.php. I want it to look like this, but it doesn't work:

```
$db['shop'] = array(
'dsn'      => '',
'hostname' => $hostname,
'username' => $username,
'password' => $password,
'database' => $database,
```

I don't know how to pass the variables into database.php. How can I do that?

Comment: check this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25457241/switch-dynamic-database-from-other-db-in-codeigniter

Comment: I have read that but its not what I want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is in the controller:

```
    $db_hostname = $databaseInfo['Hostname'];
    $db_username = $databaseInfo['Username'];
    $db_password = $databaseInfo['Password'];
    $db_database = $databaseInfo['Database'];

    $config_app = switch_db_dinamico($db_hostname, $db_username, $db_password, $db_database);

    $this->Product_shop_model->shop_db = $this->load->database($config_app, TRUE);
```

This is the helper(db_dinamic_helper):

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
function switch_db_dinamico($hostname, $username, $password, $name_db)
{
    $config_app['hostname'] = $hostname;
    $config_app['username'] = $username;
    $config_app['password'] = $password;
    $config_app['database'] = $name_db;
    $config_app['dbdriver'] = 'mysqli';
    $config_app['dbprefix'] = '';
    $config_app['pconnect'] = FALSE;
    $config_app['db_debug'] = FALSE;
    return $config_app;
}
```